# Decimal date manipulation with Pandas in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

This may be a little silly to ask but I've tried to search examples to manipulate dates in a Data Frame using pandas. But what confuses me is that my dates have this format:

```
Time A B C D

1.000347257 626.9966431 0   0   -99.98999786
1.001041651 626.9967651 0   0   -99.98999786
1.001736164 627.0130005 0   0   -99.98999786
1.002430558 627.0130005 0   0   -99.98999786
1.003124952 627.0455933 0   0   -99.98999786
1.003819466 627.0618286 0   0   -99.98999786

...

1.998263836 627.7052002 0.3417936265    0.2321419418    0.07069379836
1.998958349 627.7216187 0.3260073066    0.2284916639    0.073251158
1.999652743 627.6726074 0.3180454969    0.2164463699    0.07418025285
2.000347137 627.7371826 0.3161731362    0.2277853489    0.07479456067
2.001041651 627.7365723 0.301556468     0.2394933105    0.07920494676
2.001736164 627.7686157 0.3718534708    0.2506033182    0.07810453326

...

366.996887  625.413574  3.168393    2.114161    2.119713
366.997559  625.413391  3.163851    2.104703    2.117746
366.998261  625.461792  3.184296    2.113827    2.117964
366.998962  625.449463  3.163331    2.117869    2.116489
366.999664  625.510681  3.166895    2.126145    2.110077
```

This is an extract of the file where I have the data stored. Is there a way to convert this format using the datetime library to something like 2010-10-23? The year here is 2011 but is not specified in the data.

Thank you!

---

I looked into the documentation of pandas, though I don't understand very well, it worked. The time was in decimal format, and by day. So I just defined it and used a timestamp to declare the year that I already knew of.

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(
                      df['Time'], unit='D', origin=pd.Timestamp('2011-01-01')
                      )
```

With this the result is what I wanted it to be. And it goes through 366 days, as shown below:

```
Time A B C D
2016-01-02 00:00:30.003004800   626.996643  0.000000    0.000000    -99.989998
2016-01-02 00:01:29.998646400   626.996765  0.000000    0.000000    -99.989998
2016-01-02 00:02:30.004569600   627.013000  0.000000    0.000000    -99.989998
2016-01-02 00:03:30.000211200   627.013000  0.000000    0.000000    -99.989998
2016-01-02 00:04:29.995852800   627.045593  0.000000    0.000000    -99.989998
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2017-01-01 23:55:31.054080000   625.413574  2.706322    2.086675    2.094654
2017-01-01 23:56:29.063040000   625.413391  2.738388    2.082261    2.092784
2017-01-01 23:57:29.707200000   625.461792  2.762815    2.097127    2.091273
2017-01-01 23:58:30.351360000   625.449463  2.698989    2.105750    2.090060
2017-01-01 23:59:30.995520000   625.510681  2.751848    2.109448    2.090664
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column `Time` seems to be day fractions. If you know the year, you can convert that to a datetime column using

```
# 1 - convert the year to nanoseconds since the epoch
# 2 - add the day fraction, after you convert that to nanoseconds as well
# 3 - convert the resulting nanoseconds since the epoch to datetime
year = '2011'
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.to_datetime(year).value + df['Time']*86400*1e9)
```

which will give you e.g.

```
df
       Time           A  B  C          D                      datetime
0  1.000347  626.996643  0  0 -99.989998 2011-01-02 00:00:30.003004928
1  1.001042  626.996765  0  0 -99.989998 2011-01-02 00:01:29.998646272
2  1.001736  627.013000  0  0 -99.989998 2011-01-02 00:02:30.004569600
3  1.002431  627.013000  0  0 -99.989998 2011-01-02 00:03:30.000211200
4  1.003125  627.045593  0  0 -99.989998 2011-01-02 00:04:29.995852800
5  1.003819  627.061829  0  0 -99.989998 2011-01-02 00:05:30.001862400
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast column to datetime with pd.to_datetime():

```
df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)

df.head(2)
                             Time            A  B   C            D
0   1970-01-01 00:00:01.000347257   626.996643  0   0   -99.989998
1   1970-01-01 00:00:01.001041651   626.996765  0   0   -99.989998
```

Comment: 1970 is not what the OP expects, see "*The year here is 2011*"